# Next.js app not fetching data from API with getStaticProps or getServerSideProps

Tags: laravel, api, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from an API in my Next.js app using either getStaticProps() or getServerSideProps(), but the data is not being fetched and displayed in my app. When I use fetch() inside a component, the data is fetched and displayed correctly, but I want to use server-side rendering to improve performance and SEO.
Note: I have build my api with laravel and it works when I am using it in postman.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/students');
    const { data } = await response.json();

    return { props: { students: data } };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return { props: { students: [] } };
  }
}
```

And here's my code for rendering the data in my component:

```
export default function StudentsPage({ students }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Students</h1>

      <ul>
        {students.map((student) => (
          <li key={student.id}>
            {student.name} ({student.email})
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I load the page, I get the fetch failed and 500 internal server error which there is no error with my api endpoints.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

I want to get the list of students comming from my api endpoints using the getStaticProps or getServerSideProps in nextjs.

Answer (score 2):

getStaticProps happens when you build your application.

> The data required to render the page is available at build time ahead
> of a user’s request

So make sure that http://localhost:8000/ is available during that time.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props